# Xcode 14 beta 2 Command CompileAssetCatalog failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: swift, xcode, compiler-errors

My project builds perfectly fine in Xcode 13, but when I build in Xcode 14 beta 2, it keeps giving error build: Command CompileAssetCatalog failed with a nonzero exit code.

I have already tried deleting DerivedData, clean build folder, and restarting Xcode and computer.

```
CompileAssetCatalog /Users/jevonmao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SMHS-esckkqqksdgcewfyejujeeeukzmg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SMHS.app /Users/jevonmao/Documents/GitHub/SMHS/Sources/SMHS\ (iOS)/Preview\ Content/Preview\ Assets.xcassets /Users/jevonmao/Documents/GitHub/SMHS/ElegantCalendar.xcassets /Users/jevonmao/Documents/GitHub/SMHS/Sources/SMHS\ (iOS)/Assets.xcassets (in target 'SMHS (iOS)' from project 'SMHS')
    cd /Users/jevonmao/Documents/GitHub/SMHS
    /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/actool --output-format human-readable-text --notices --warnings --export-dependency-info /Users/jevonmao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SMHS-esckkqqksdgcewfyejujeeeukzmg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/SMHS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SMHS\ \(iOS\).build/assetcatalog_dependencies --output-partial-info-plist /Users/jevonmao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SMHS-esckkqqksdgcewfyejujeeeukzmg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/SMHS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SMHS\ \(iOS\).build/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist --app-icon AppIcon --accent-color AccentColor --compress-pngs --enable-on-demand-resources YES --optimization time --filter-for-device-model iPhone14,2 --filter-for-device-os-version 15.5 --development-region en --target-device iphone --target-device ipad --minimum-deployment-target 14.0 --platform iphonesimulator --compile /Users/jevonmao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SMHS-esckkqqksdgcewfyejujeeeukzmg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SMHS.app /Users/jevonmao/Documents/GitHub/SMHS/Sources/SMHS\ \(iOS\)/Preview\ Content/Preview\ Assets.xcassets /Users/jevonmao/Documents/GitHub/SMHS/ElegantCalendar.xcassets /Users/jevonmao/Documents/GitHub/SMHS/Sources/SMHS\ \(iOS\)/Assets.xcassets

'cyclone' is not a recognized processor for this target (ignoring processor)
'cyclone' is not a recognized processor for this target (ignoring processor)
'cyclone' is not a recognized processor for this target (ignoring processor)
'cyclone' is not a recognized processor for this target (ignoring processor)
'cyclone' is not a recognized processor for this target (ignoring processor)
'cyclone' is not a recognized processor for this target (ignoring processor)
'cyclone' is not a recognized processor for this target (ignoring processor)
'cyclone' is not a recognized processor for this target (ignoring processor)
'cyclone' is not a recognized processor for this target (ignoring processor)
'cyclone' is not a recognized processor for this target (ignoring processor)
'cyclone' is not a recognized processor for this target (ignoring processor)
'cyclone' is not a recognized processor for this target (ignoring processor)
'cyclone' is not a recognized processor for this target (ignoring processor)
'cyclone' is not a recognized processor for this target (ignoring processor)
'cyclone' is not a recognized processor for this target (ignoring processor)
'cyclone' is not a recognized processor for this target (ignoring processor)
'cyclone' is not a recognized processor for this target (ignoring processor)
'cyclone' is not a recognized processor for this target (ignoring processor)
Command CompileAssetCatalog failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Comment: Same issue i am also facing. Couldn't find the solution yet, trying it.

Answer (score 0):

This indicates that xcode build command is failing - most likely due to not being able to find appropriate Command Line Tools.

Make sure that

> XCode > Preferences > Locations > Command Line Tools

dropdown is not empty. Click it and select the available option.